# Issue with FontImageSource Glyph when using a Binding

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, fonts, glyph, material-design-icons

Using Xamarin Forms 5 and Visual Studio 2022.

I have added the `materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf` to a Fonts folder of the PCL project only and marked it as an Embedded Resource.

I have added the following in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file:

```cs
[assembly: ExportFont("materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf", Alias = "mdi")]
```

The following XAML works fine:

```xml
<Image x:DataType="models:IPageResourceProvider"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        IsVisible="{Binding IconType, Converter={StaticResource IconTypeConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static enums:IconType.MaterialDesignIcon}}">
    <Image.Source>
        <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xF0B55;"
                          FontFamily="mdi"
                          Size="32"
                          Color="Black" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

But I want to bind the Glyph, however the following just shows a 5 as the Image (the last character of the unicode):

```xml
<Image x:DataType="models:IPageResourceProvider"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
        IsVisible="{Binding IconType, Converter={StaticResource IconTypeConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static enums:IconType.MaterialDesignIcon}}">
    <Image.Source>
        <FontImageSource Glyph="{Binding IconName}"
                          FontFamily="mdi"
                          Size="32"
                          Color="Black" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

The interface IPageResourceProvider has the following property:

```cs
string IconName {get; }
```

And the implementation returns:

```cs
string IconName => "\uF0B55";
```

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong with this, any thoughts welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C#` represent a UTF-32 glyph using 4 bytes.

Example in `C#` for glyph `U+10FFFD`. Please note the upper case `U`:

```
public string IconName => "\U0010FFFD";
```

See also the note on four-digit and eight-digit Unicode escape codes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types#string-literals).

Example in `XAML` for glyph `U+10FFFD`:

```
Glyph="&#x10FFFD;"
```

Comment: To clarify (because this confused me at first): upper-case `U` is required when there are more than 4 hex digits. In the question `\uF0B55` became `\uF0B5` followed by `5`. To be safe (when glyph is followed by other characters), give all 8 digits as shown in this answer. For question, the glyph becomes `\U000F0B55`.